# My video doesn't show up with youtubebackground api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, youtube-api

I have a issue, a issue that still remains after 1 week, couldn't discover why my video doesn't show up using the youtubebackground api,
Basicly i am using bootstrap and i defined a container for my video
**like this:**

```
<section class="content_section">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="video">

    </div>
</section>
```

then i used the youtubeBackgroundapi here is the order of the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.youtubebackground.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<!-- this is where we put our custom functions -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

my app.js is where i put the javascript code related to the behaviour of the video

**like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video').YTPlayer({
    fitToBackground: true,
    videoId: 'mcFYvy0L2vI',
    playerVars: {
      modestbranding: 0,
      autoplay: 1,
      controls: 1,
      showinfo: 0,
      branding: 0,
      rel: 0,
      autohide: 0,
      start: 10
    }
  });
})
```

and finnally i changed my css like the docs said to do:

```
#video {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}

.ytplayer-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

i have no idea why it doesn't show up, i just can see the white content of the div, nothing in there, do i need to run my app in a server to put that on work?

Comment: Well, for starters you don't have an element with the class "ytplayer-container"

Comment: i tried to use this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/mLwyyay9/4/ but not working :S

Comment: he doesn't use the ytplayer.container :S

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the right libraries and in the right order? **Note** that you should include jquery **before** including the jquery youtube background script (**see my HTML**).  I was able to get it working in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fxx7zfhb/) and in a Stack Overflow code snippet (see below)

**EDIT** Another discrepancy is that you are including Jquery **1.11.3** where the Jquery Youtube Background docs include **1.10.2**. Perhaps this is making the difference?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video').YTPlayer({
    fitToBackground: true,
    videoId: 'mcFYvy0L2vI',
    playerVars: {
      modestbranding: 0,
      autoplay: 1,
      controls: 1,
      showinfo: 0,
      branding: 0,
      rel: 0,
      autohide: 0,
      start: 10
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#video {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}

.ytplayer-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rochestb/jQuery.YoutubeBackground/dbdfa723/src/jquery.youtubebackground.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="content_section">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="video">

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: i have everything like you have, thats why i don't get it why it doesn't show up :/

Comment: You have to show a fuller code example then. And you are sure that you are including the libraries in the right order? In particular, jquery **before** the jquery youtube background?

Comment: yes, just a question, this works without server side? right?

Comment: Correct. Just as in the JSFiddle I included and the one you mentioned.

Comment: see above i included my scripts reference, i don't get any error at the console thats why i am soo confused about this

Comment: you are right very good, but now it fits all my page and i still can't see the video but i see something loading in a white page

Comment: You should either change your question or ask a new one.